# iOS programmatic grouped table empty

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview, loadview

I have a programmatically implemented tableView, in the grouped style.

All I am getting is the gray pinstripes when it should be populated. So it is loading, but not ... something...

What more is necessary?
If no more, then where else ought I look?

Also, how can I make the background color of the table the same as the cell's white color?

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    UITableView *view = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    self.view = view;

    [view reloadData];

}
```

Is viewDidLoad necessary?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Thank you,

- Morkrom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide your tableView with data.

For staters you'll need to define a `dataSource`. Its common to just use your viewController as the dataSource.

```
// in the .h find something similar and add <UITableViewDataSource>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
```

then when you make the tableView.

```
view.datasource = self;
```

Then you'll need to provide the data itself. Implement these methods:

```
#pragma mark - UITableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"A Cell"];

    return cell;
}
```

Those methods will create 3 sections each with 3 rows. All the cells will just say A Cell. This is the basis for all tableViews. Just customize the data :)

Comment: So just for fun, what if the datasource is some other class?

Comment: No problem. As long as that other class has the `<UITableViewDataSource>` you just need to set your `view.datasource = THATCLASS` and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set dataSource and delegate properties for your table view so it will be able to pull data from them:

```
UITableView *view = ...
view.dataSource = self;
view.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

have protocol in .h file   and attach delegate and source with file owner